# PBS jobs not starting

Tags: startup, pbs

I am new to PBS. Our system admin left (to an other workplace). Our claster was sut down for a weekend because of some reason.
Now i'am trying to restart it. There is 1 server machine, and the other machines load the operating system via drbl.
There are some files we need to update manually after all restart - i did it.
Then i started pbs_mom and  trqauthd on all machines.
Then i started pbs_server and maui on the server machine.

When a job is started with qsub, it does not run: it remain quined. It is possible to start it with  qrun. pbsnodes -a show the nodes are free, expect one, which is down. (unkown reason). showq qstat qdel comands works on the cluster.

Thanks for any help: Gergo

Comment: We fixed it. The pbs_mom got a wrong ip adress (of the cluster) on the clients.

Comment: This post seems to be off-topic here since the problem is specific to your setup. The only advice I can give that might be helpful to others is that your cluster startup **AND** shutdown procedures should be fully automated **AND** documented. Usually when the need arises you have something else to keep your mind busy.